# Why does $\int_1^\infty \sin(x \log x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ converge?

Tags: calculus, integration

Why does $\int_1^\infty \sin(x\log x)\,dx$ converge?

I haven't got a clue about where to being with this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Similar question posted here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/651951/does-the-integral-int-1-infty-sinx-log-x-mathrmdx-converge

Comment: I've seen that question and was hoping someone could provide some clarity on the answer.

Comment: If you've already found an answer and you don't understand it, you should open your question with that! And explain what you don't understand.

Comment: The upshot is, by splitting the integral into pieces, you can write it as a convergent Alternating series. Drawing the graph of $f(x)=\sin(x\log x)$ should help here.

Comment: In fact, this question has been duplicated *many* times.  Why this is the one that gets closed - who knows. :)

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha says no](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sin%28xln%28x%29%29+from+x%3D1+to+x%3Dinfinity)...

But [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/106728/78722) says yes! Looks like W|A is wrong on this one?

Comment: @BennettGardiner Like Mathematica's Integrate command, W|A tests for absolute convergence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at a graph.

[image]

It *appears* that the graph oscillates up and down over the $x$-axis and that the labeled areas are decreasing to zero from left to right.  In fact, it's not hard to *prove* these statements, namely

$$\int_1^\infty \sin(x\log x)\,dx = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} I_n$$

and that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} I_n = 0$ with $0<I_{n+1}<I_n$.  This boils down to the fact the area $I_k$ is bound on the left by the $k^\text{th}$ of $sin(x\log(x))$ and on the right by the next root.  Furthermore, these roots are exactly the spots where 
$$x\log(x) = k\pi,$$
for some integer $k$. The fact that the distance between consecutive roots tends to zero boils down to the fact that $x\log(x)$ is an increasing, convex function.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. Based on the answer that was linked, I need to prove that $I_n$ is a sign-alternating and monotonically decreasing in absolute value to zero (therefore giving me a Leibniz series which converges). I kind of understand how to show the sign-alternating, but have no idea how to show the monotonically decreasing in absolute value to 0.

Comment: @MarkEmacr I posted my answer prematurely since I saw the close votes coming. I hope the edit helps.