# About the integral $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sin(x\,\log x)\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, contour-integration

It is an interesting exercise to show that the function $f(x)=\sin(x\log x)$ is Riemann-integrable over $\mathbb{R}^+$ (as shown by [robjohn](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/13854/robjohn) in [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106710/does-int-1-infty-sinx-log-xdx-converge), for instance). Even more interesting is to notice that:

$$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx = \sum_{n\geq 0}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}\left(\log x\right)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\,dx=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)^{2n}},\tag{1}$$
with a series related with the one appearing in many [sophomore's dreams](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237513/series-as-an-integral-sophomores-dream).

Moreover, by using [Lambert's W function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html) it is not difficult to check that:
$$ I = \int_{1}^{+\infty}\sin(x\log x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin u}{1+W(u)}\,du. \tag{2} $$

> Now my question: **is it possible to give a nice closed form to the RHS of $(2)$ through countour integration, the residue theorem or other techniques?**

For instance, is there a closed form for the almost-digamma-sum:
$$ g(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\frac{1}{1+W(x+2n\pi)}-\frac{1}{1+W(2n\pi)}\right) \tag{3}$$
? If so, we have just to compute $\int_{0}^{2\pi}g(x)\sin x\,dx$.

Comment: @Dr.MV: $1+W(x)$ equals zero in $x=-\frac{1}{e}$ and $W(x)$ has a logarithmic growth. Both these facts follow from the definition of Lambert's W function.

Comment: Are we talking only about the standard branch of $W$?

Comment: @tired: yes, absolutely. Obviously, in order to compute $(2)$ through complex analysis we have to consider every branch.

Comment: @Jack Do you know this paper: 
http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~djeffrey/Offprints/W-adv-cm.pdf
there is an excellent discussion of the different branches of $W$ which may help you to find an appropriate contour

Comment: @tired: many thanks, it could be useful.

Comment: Wolfy says that $\int_{0.1}^{1000} sin(x\ log(x)) dx = 0.585684$.

Comment: @martycohen If you replace the upper bound $1000$ by $10^7$ you get $0.4$. Evaluating this integral numerically is very hard to do the slow fall-off and rapid osccilations.

Comment: Not Riemann integrable, but such that the improper Riemann integral converges.

Answer (score 4):

I seem to have an idea for a solution to your integral through other techniques than you might have anticipated. By the way, I am extremely uncertain of my work, so please edit the question before immediately down-voting if you see a problem. Thanks. I want to point out that the final solution is hopefully easier for you. (Point of answer is to solve for $I$)

$$\int_1^\infty\text{d}x \sin(x \log x)=I$$

Now multiply the numerator and denominator of the fraction $I/1$ by J, where $$J=\int_1^e\frac{\text{d}x}{x\log x}$$

From this, you get (with substitution in $J$ of $x=y$) $\frac{IJ}{J}=\cdots$

$$I=\frac{1}{\int_1^e \sqrt{x\log x}}\int_1^\infty \int_1^e \frac{\text{d}x\text{d}x \sin(x\log x)}{\sqrt{x\log x}}$$

Now, the multiplied integral $(J)$ can in fact be solved in terms of the error function.
I will solve for $J$ by substitution and Fundamental Theorem of Calculus you will see why later.

$$\int\frac{\text{d}x}{\sqrt{x\log x}}$$

Substitute out $a=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ and $\text{d}a=-\frac{\text{d}x}{2x^{3/2}}$
I have checked the algebra.
$$\int \frac{-2 \text{d}u}{u^2\sqrt{-2\log u}}\implies -i\sqrt{2}\int \frac{\text{d}u}{u^2\sqrt{\log u}}$$

Next substitute $c=\log b$ and $\text{d}c=\frac{\text{d}b}{b}$
That leaves us with

$$-i\sqrt{2}\int \frac{e^{-b}\text{d}b}{\sqrt{b}}$$

The next part is a bit weird. This was beyond my skill level, so I gave this to W|A who gladly accepted. It [punched out](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20e%5E-x%20%2Fsqrt%20x):

$$-i\sqrt{2\pi} \text{erf}(\sqrt b)$$

Under recollection that $a=\log b$, you get

$$-i\sqrt{2\pi} \text{erf}(\sqrt{\log a})$$

Then recall that $a=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$, you get

$$-i\sqrt{2\pi} \text{erf}(\sqrt{\log \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}})$$

Simplifying gains:

$$-i\sqrt{2\pi}\text{erf}(\sqrt{\frac{-\log x}{2}})$$

From that, solving for $J$ is a piece of cake.

$$\int_1^e \frac{\text{d}x}{\sqrt{x \log x}}=-i\sqrt{2\pi}(\text{erf}(\sqrt{\frac{-\log e}{2}}))-(-i\sqrt{2\pi}(\text{erf}(\sqrt{\frac{-\log 1}{2}})))=\sqrt{2\pi}\text{erfi}(1/\sqrt{2})\approx 2.38$$

This ugly mess results in a very little change. But in reality, that "very little change" is extremely important. DO NOT change the right side. We have something very special in mind for that.

$$I=\frac{1}{\sqrt {2\pi}\text{erfi}(1/\sqrt{2})}\int_1^\infty \int_1^e \frac{\text{d}x\text{d}x \sin(x\log x)}{\sqrt{x\log x}}$$

So, I do recognize the inverse of $x \log x$ as $W(\log x)$, so for the entire RHS, substitute $x=W(\log u)$

$$I=\frac{1}{\sqrt {2\pi}\text{erfi}(1/\sqrt{2})}\int_{0}^\infty \int_0^{\Omega} \frac{(W^{\prime}(\log u)^2)\text{d}u\text{d}u \sqrt{u}\sin u}{u}$$

We easily recognize something nice! Split up the integral into three parts that can be used. (integral of sinc function is what is recognized.) Not entirely sure of that step (though pretty sure), please let me know in the comments if that is OK to do.

$$I=\frac{1}{\sqrt {2\pi}\text{erfi}(1/\sqrt{2})}*\int_0^\Omega (W^\prime (\log u)^2)\sqrt{u}\text{d}u * \int_0^\infty (\frac{\sin u}{u})\implies$$

$$I=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt2 \text{erfi}(1/\sqrt{2})}\int_0^\Omega \sqrt{u}\space W^{\prime}(\ln u)\text{d}u$$

After this step, however, I am at a loss. I hope that this new solution brings you closer to your goal. Sorry for not being able to complete it.

Comment: @RonGordon Do you mind checking the step my last step? (Seperating Integrals) You are easily the king at integrals and I am trying to learn the properties.

Comment: You have an integral with ${\rm d}x{\rm d}x$. This does not make sense. It should be $\int\int\frac{{\rm d}x\rm{d} y\sin(x\log(x))}{\sqrt{y\log(y)}}$.

Comment: The idea behind the $\text{d}x \text{d}x$ is similar to a $\text{d}x \text{d}y$ but with the substitution of $x=y$ But because of the fact that we maintain that fact through out the problem and only substitute the same things for both $x$ and $y$, we are allowed to do that. I hope you can get what I am saying. @Winther

Comment: @Winther You can see what I was trying to do though, yes?

Comment: You are not allowed to do that.

Comment: @Winther Why not? It makes algebraic sense. Is there a place that describes why I cannot do that?

Comment: Perhaps better to use an example. Take $I = \int_0^1 x{\rm d}x$. With your method you have $I^2 = \int_0^1\int_0^1 x^2{\rm d}x{\rm d}x$. Can you show me how you would compute this integral? The true result is $I = 1/2$ and $I^2 = 1/4$.

Comment: Well, that isn't how I would evaluate $I$ in the first place. I would multiply and divide a helpful integral $J$ that would make it easier.

Comment: I'm trying to show you why your method does not make sense. If it makes sense that you should be able to integrate it and get the right result.

Comment: Do you mind moving this into chat? I am getting confused with what you're counterargument is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33229/discussion-between-winther-and-apple).